# PHP Store the new line strings into array

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on my PHP script to fetch the strings by using explode so I can store the strings into the array. I have got a problem with my code because when I split the strings to store them into the array, I will get like this:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => 0.1 noname.gif [2] => 0.2 what-is-bootstrap.png )
```

Here is what it should be:

```
Array ( [0] => 0.1 noname.gif [1] => 0.2 what-is-bootstrap.png)
```

Here is what it show in the results:

```
attid: 0.1 filename: noname.gif
attid: 0.2 filename: what-is-bootstrap.png
```

Here is the code:

```
<?php

$attached = 'attid: 0.1 filename: noname.gif
attid: 0.2 filename: what-is-bootstrap.png';
$attached_files = explode('attid:', $attached);
$attached_files = str_replace('filename:', '', $attached_files);

?>
```

I don't know how to store the strings into the array with each key like 0 and 1.

Can you please show me an example how I can store the strings into the array when I split the strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the following line...

```
$attached_files = array_values(array_map('trim', array_filter($attached_files)));
```

it will do 3 things.

The `array_filter()` will remove any empty lines.  The reason for the first one is that as you `explode()` on `'attid:'`, it will consider there to be a value before the first occurrence - which is blank.  You could just do `array_shift()` to remove the first item, but `array_filter()` will filter any empty lines.

Secondly - you will find there are trailing new lines etc.  So the `array_map()` with `trim` will ensure any excess whitespace is removed.

Lastly `array_values()` will re-index the array to start from 0.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, so in which line I should add the code that come with array_map?

Comment: Add it anywhere after the line with `explode()`.  Although it would ideally be just after as it would ensure that empty lines are removed before any other processing is done.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'm getting this `Array ( [1] => 0.1 noname.gif [2] => 0.2 what-is-bootstrap.png )`, so how I can set the key that start with 0 instead of 1?

Comment: Added `array_values()` to re-index the array.

Comment: Thank you very much for this as this is what I am looking for exactly!